# How to exchange the places of the items in a python list?

Tags: python, list, reindex

A text is divided in groups with seven letters. Each group is scrambled with the key `6015423` (letter with index `0` on index `6`, letter with index `1` on index `0`, letter with index `2` on index `1...`).

Instead of the correct word "serpent" (tried it only with the first seven-letter group, the same problem occurs when `%7` is left out) my code yields a false result beginning with index `4`: serpsne.

What is the mistake?

```
list=['e','r','n','t','e','p','s']
clear=[]
for x in list:    
    if list.index(x)%7==0:
        a=list[list.index(x)+6]
    elif list.index(x)%7==1:
        a=list[list.index(x)-1]
    elif list.index(x)%7==2:
        a=list[list.index(x)-1]
    elif list.index(x)%7==3:
        a=list[list.index(x)+2]
    elif list.index(x)%7==4:
        a=x
    elif list.index(x)%7==5:
        a=list[list.index(x)-3]
    else:               
        a=list[list.index(x)-6]
    clear.append(a)
clear=''.join(clear)
print(clear)
```

(Don´t know why this box inserts two blank lines after for and else, my code has no blank lines.)

Comment: You could swap the values by index.
list[0],list[1] = list[1],list[0]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you're doing this much! Try this one below:

```
lst=['e','r','n','t','e','p','s']
clear=[]
key='6015423'
for x in key:
    clear.append(lst[int(x)])

clear=''.join(clear)
print(clear)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used the modulo thing because 'list' , unlike in my example given above, consists of many seven-letter groups, all transposed with the identical key. I'll try to multiply 'key' in your code so that it becomes as long as 'list'.

Answer (score 0):

Because list.index('e') is always 0.

It will find the index of the first occurence of 'e', not the second one and hence it will never execute this:

```
elif list.index(x)%7==4:
    a=x
```

Try to run this code:

```
list=['e','r','n','t','e','p','s']
for x in list:
print ( list.index(x))
```

You will get 0123056 instead of 0123456

Comment: I'll bear this in mind, thanks! Is there a way to find the indices of further occurences of an item?

Comment: sure, you can do e.g.

    `all_occurences_of_e = [ i for i in range(len(lst)) if lst[i]=='e' ]`

by the way it is probably not a good idea to call your list variable 'list', as 'list' is also the name of the class